# Builder for ElasticSearch query DSL in Yii2 (or standalone)

Tags: php, elasticsearch, yii2, elasticsearch-dsl

As far as I can see, the only way to make a query to ElasticSearch in Yii2 is to run `ElasticModel::find()->query($query)`, where `$query` is a complex array containing the actual query written in ElasticSearch query DSL.

The query is huge and quickly becomes unmanageable. For SQL Yii2 provides a powerful query builder class that supports tons of useful methods like `andWhere()`. For ElasticSearch everything goes into one gigantic query expression, very much like building an SQL expression string by hand.

Is there any high-level wrapper for ElasticSearch query DSL for Yii2? If not, is there a standalone library with similar functionality?

Comment: We are looking for this as well, any progress on finding a solution?

Comment: I took some time to get used to ES paradigm. All queries are pretty much nested and self-sufficient. So I'm building parts of queries as separate queries and then combine them together. That's manageable enough for me.

Comment: Yeah we are kind of into the same pattern here. Thanks

Comment: There's also [elastica](http://elastica.io/), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: We ended up writing our own class for generating json-query-object the we send to ES trough yii/elasticsearch/query. Not super dynamic but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to build for version 1.6 of elastic, I have created a query builder for my company and published [it here](https://github.com/itvisionsy/php-es-mapper/blob/master/query_builder_README.md)

You will use it as a standalone query builder, and at the end you will need to get the final query array and pass it to the query executer.

To install it, you can simply use composer `composer require itvisionsy/php-es-orm` or download the zipped version [here](https://github.com/itvisionsy/php-es-mapper/archive/v1.7.4.zip).

The link above contains some examples, and here is a copy:

```
//build the query using different methods
$query = \ItvisionSy\EsMapper\QueryBuilder::make()
            ->where('key1','some value') //term clause
            ->where('key2',$intValue,'>') //range clause
            ->where('key3','value','!=') //must_not term clause
            ->where('key4', ['value1','value2']) //terms clause
            ->where('email', '@hotmail.com', '*=') //wildcard search for all @hotmail.com emails
            ->sort('key1','asc') //first sort option
            ->sort('key2',['order'=>'asc','mode'=>'avg']) //second sort option
            ->from(20)->size(20) //results from 20 to 39
            ->toArray();

//modify the query as you need
$query['aggs']=['company'=>['terms'=>['field'=>'company']]];

//then execute it against a type query
$result = TypeQuery::query($query);
//i am not sure about Yii way to execute, according to the question, it should be:
$result = ElasticModel::find()->query($query);
```

The package also include a simple ElasticSearch ORM class which maybe useful for you. Take a look at it [here](https://github.com/itvisionsy/php-es-mapper/blob/master/README.md).

Hope this helps you...